Very slow INSERT performance when using data generation functions
I am trying to get some random data into a table with 1 million entries, and for some reason it is very slow to apply the WAL changes. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. These are my CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Companies (
    ID SYMBOL,
    Name VARCHAR,
    FoundedYear INT,
    Industry SYMBOL,
    Country SYMBOL,
    Employees INT,
    FoundationDate TIMESTAMP
) TIMESTAMP(FoundationDate) PARTITION BY DAY WAL;

WITH sortedCompanies AS (
SELECT
    'COMP' || x AS ID,
    rnd_str('Tech Innovators Inc.', 'Health Plus Ltd.', 'Eco Solutions LLC', 'FinTech Pioneers', 'AgriGoods Inc.') AS Name,
    rnd_int(2000, 2020, 0) AS FoundedYear, -- Random years between 2000 and 2020
    rnd_symbol('Technology', 'Healthcare', 'Environmental', 'Finance', 'Agriculture') AS Industry,
    rnd_symbol('USA', 'UK', 'Germany', 'France', 'Japan') AS Country,
    rnd_int(10, 1000, 0) AS Employees, -- Random number of employees between 10 and 1000
    timestamp_sequence(to_timestamp('2010-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), rnd_int(2592000, 31536000, 0)) AS FoundationDate -- Random dates over several years
FROM long_sequence(1000000, 128349234,4327897) x order by FoundationDate
) 
INSERT BATCH 100000 INTO Companies SELECT * from sortedCompanies;

It takes almost 5 minutes for the WAL to apply completely and show the 1 million rows. As you see, my data is generated with a timestamp_sequence function, so it should always be in order. I am using the built-in data generation functions, and the SELECT itself takes about 400 ms, so I was expecting this INSERT to be very fast and was surprised by the poor performance. Any hints? Thanks!

It turns out the culprit was the definition of the ID Symbol column. As specified at the QuestDB docs, the default Symbol capacity is 256, and using a small symbol capacity compared to the real cardinality of the values can lead to poor performance. I kind of was aware of this, but I was expecting the performance impact to be way smaller.
After adjusting the Symbol capacity to a higher number the insertion was instantaneous (it basically takes as long to finish the INSERT as it does to just SELECT the data, below half a second).
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Companies (
    ID SYMBOL CAPACITY 50000000 NOCACHE,
    Name VARCHAR,
    FoundedYear INT,
    Industry SYMBOL,
    Country SYMBOL,
    Employees INT,
    FoundationDate TIMESTAMP
) TIMESTAMP(FoundationDate) PARTITION BY MONTH WAL;

Moreover, I noticed that for my use case I actually didn't really need a Symbol type in this column, as I am storing unique values, which is not ideal by far for this data type. It would be better to just use a VARCHAR column here. Since I am just using a numerical value with a fix prefix, I actually ended up storing the column as a Long. Of course INSERT is still as performant as when I had a Symbol.
